# Not able to login user with same credentials as imported database as it uses encrypt fields such as email

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, encryption, import

Due to some data related issues,I imported dev database to my local database that is running via docker however I am not able to login a user with same credentials that are working on dev server/database. I noticed that fields like email etc are using rails encrypt database field.
I am not able to login user with same username password ,if some one knows what might be causing it and a solution to it,that would be wonderful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to use the same encryption key on your local system that you are using on the dev server.

Comment: @dbugger I am using same lockbox master key used on dev server but it still does not seem to work,I have even restarted the server for changes to reflect

Comment: What about the app's secret key base?

Comment: That is also the dev one @dbugger

Comment: something is out of synch between the two environments -- that's what you need to locate